# pyqtgraph/chaco/guiqwt: Fast scrolling timetrace demo

Tags: python, pyside, interactive, chaco, pyqtgraph

I want to implement a fast scrolling timetrace tool in python. The timetrace data is already all in memory in a `numpy` array and is big (>1e6 samples). I need a tool for quick visual inspection.

I [already tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824718/python-matplotlib-pyside-fast-timetrace-scrolling) using Matplotlib+PySide but the update speed is not fast enough.

Can you reproduce the [Matplotlib+Pyside demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824718/python-matplotlib-pyside-fast-timetrace-scrolling) in another toolkit like pygraphqt/chaco/quiqwt? I don't know any of them and I'm willing to learn the one that perform better in this application.

To be useful in my workflow, the chosen framework should allow to run the plot from an interactive ipython session and should be fast and extensible  (eventually I will need several plots scrolled in sync on the same windows). In principle pyqtgraph, guiqwt or chaco all seem good candidates. But let judge on a real example.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI: guiqwt is a very nice library, but it is based on pyqwt, which is no longer maintained. There's a new version sans-pyqwt in the planning called guiplot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the pyqtgraph version. I tried to keep the code as similar as I could to the original demo. On my system, pyqtgraph only runs about 5x faster than matplotlib, and is still pretty slow (~1fps) when all of the data is visible. The major performance differences between matplotlib and pyqtgraph are in *throughput*--how rapidly new data can be plotted.

For better performance, I'd recommend looking at some of the GPU-based plotting libraries like visvis or galry. Pyqtgraph will be adding GPU support in the future, but it's not there yet. There are some efforts to bring matplotlib to the GPU as well, but I haven't seen any results from that yet..

```
## adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824718/python-matplotlib-pyside-fast-timetrace-scrolling

from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

N_SAMPLES = 1e6

def test_plot():
    time = np.arange(N_SAMPLES)*1e-3
    sample = np.random.randn(N_SAMPLES)

    plt = pg.PlotWidget(title="Use the slider to scroll and the spin-box to set the width")
    plt.addLegend()
    plt.plot(time, sample, name="Gaussian noise")
    q = ScrollingToolQT(plt)
    return q   # WARNING: it's important to return this object otherwise
            # python will delete the reference and the GUI will not respond!


class ScrollingToolQT(object):
    def __init__(self, fig):
        # Setup data range variables for scrolling
        self.fig = fig
        self.xmin, self.xmax = fig.plotItem.vb.childrenBounds()[0]
        self.step = 1 # axis units

        self.scale = 1e3 # conversion betweeen scrolling units and axis units

        # Retrive the QMainWindow used by current figure and add a toolbar
        # to host the new widgets
        self.win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        self.win.show()
        self.win.resize(800,600)
        self.win.setCentralWidget(fig)
        self.toolbar = QtGui.QToolBar()
        self.win.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, self.toolbar)

        # Create the slider and spinbox for x-axis scrolling in toolbar
        self.set_slider(self.toolbar)
        self.set_spinbox(self.toolbar)

        # Set the initial xlimits coherently with values in slider and spinbox
        self.set_xlim = self.fig.setXRange
        self.set_xlim(0, self.step)

    def set_slider(self, parent):
        # Slider only support integer ranges so use ms as base unit
        smin, smax = self.xmin*self.scale, self.xmax*self.scale

        self.slider = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, parent=parent)
        self.slider.setTickPosition(QtGui.QSlider.TicksAbove)
        self.slider.setTickInterval((smax-smin)/10.)
        self.slider.setMinimum(smin)
        self.slider.setMaximum(smax-self.step*self.scale)
        self.slider.setSingleStep(self.step*self.scale/5.)
        self.slider.setPageStep(self.step*self.scale)
        self.slider.setValue(0)  # set the initial position
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.xpos_changed)
        parent.addWidget(self.slider)

    def set_spinbox(self, parent):
        self.spinb = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox(parent=parent)
        self.spinb.setDecimals(3)
        self.spinb.setRange(0.001, 3600.)
        self.spinb.setSuffix(" s")
        self.spinb.setValue(self.step)   # set the initial width
        self.spinb.valueChanged.connect(self.xwidth_changed)
        parent.addWidget(self.spinb)

    def xpos_changed(self, pos):
        #pprint("Position (in scroll units) %f\n" %pos)
        #        self.pos = pos/self.scale
        pos /= self.scale
        self.set_xlim(pos, pos + self.step, padding=0)

    def xwidth_changed(self, xwidth):
        #pprint("Width (axis units) %f\n" % step)
        if xwidth <= 0: return
        self.step = xwidth
        self.slider.setSingleStep(self.step*self.scale/5.)
        self.slider.setPageStep(self.step*self.scale)
        old_xlim = self.fig.plotItem.vb.viewRange()[0]
        self.xpos_changed(old_xlim[0] * self.scale)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = pg.mkQApp()
    q = test_plot()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost a drop-in replacement! An it run significantly faster than MPL.